# Как осуществить проверку пользователя, в форме входа, на уровне модели?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста. 
Как осуществить проверку пользователя, в форме входа, на уровне модели? Выводил ошибку если нет логина пользователя в базе данных. Я как понимаю это делается через валидацию, но не знаю как сделать?

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # включаем has_secure_password для шифрования
  has_secure_password
  # Валидация формы регистрации
  validates :login, presence: true, length: {minimum: 3}
  validates :email, email: true
  validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 8}
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, length: {minimum: 8}
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => false

  #Валидация формы входа пользователя

end


    # Маршрут login, для входа пользователей
get '/login' do
# Если выполнен вход происходит переадресация на страницу пользователя
  if session[:user_id] != nil
    redirect '/user/' + User.find(session[:user_id]).login
  end


  erb :login
end
```

Comment: Вы самостоятельно реализуете авторизацию, без devise? Добавьте код контроллера и модели к вопросу. Правильно понимаю, речь о форме входа (sing in), а не о форме регистрации (sign up)? В данном случае речь не о валидации, тут в контроллере нужно искать пользователя с введённым логином и проверять, его ли это пароль. И выводить "Логин или пароль введён неправильно" в случае любой ошибки - согласно требований безопасности не стоит подсказывать, в каком именно поле ошибка

Comment: а что имеете ввиду под devise? Код добавил, Да речь о входе идет

Comment: devise - это гем для авторизации. К сожалению, сейчас нет времени на написание полноценного ответа. Почитайте в [туториале](https://www.softcover.io/read/db8803f7/ruby_on_rails_tutorial_3rd_edition_russian/log_in_log_out), как это делается. Да и остальной туториал вам наверняка пригодится :)

Comment: @Василиса Спасибо